# Cannot retrieve full text using Twitter API V2

Tags: twitter, twitter-api-v2

I’m testing to retrieve full text for both tweet and retweet using postman.

- retweet ID: 1664275386073767943
- conversation_id (original tweet ID): 1664274549503070216

API call:

```
https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets?ids=1664275386073767943&tweet.fields=author_id,conversation_id,created_at,entities,geo,id,in_reply_to_user_id,lang,public_metrics,referenced_tweets,source,text&expansions=referenced_tweets.id&user.fields=location,description,entities,public_metrics,created_at,profile_image_url&place.fields=contained_within,country,country_code,full_name,geo,id,name,place_type
```

The [includes.tweets.0.text] output is truncated:

```
US sanctions Chinese and Mexican entities in a bid to combat the fentanyl issue
The U.S. has imposed sanctions on 17 individuals and entities based in China and Mexico for participating in the global distribution of equipment utilized in illicit drug manufacturing.
#China #US… https://twitter.com/i/web/status/1664274549503070216 https://twitter.com/spotlightoncn/status/1664274549503070216/video/1
```

Does anyone know why?